# Remove count beneath group

Tags: 2007, document-library

I have added a count to the view of a document library. I'm happy with the totals at the top and next to the name (see orange boxes) but I want to get rid of the totals under each group (see blue box).

Is this possible?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is using CSS to hide those an option to you?

Comment: Is that something that would be done in SharePoint Designer?

Comment: Yes Enilorac, you would have to use the designer in order to remove the "Count". Open the list in the designer and then move your cursor on the Count use back space to delete it. It will delete the count from all the "Group Name".

Comment: Will this mean the view can then only be edited through Designer?

Comment: @spStacker am I right?

Comment: Hi Enilorac, by edit - do you mean "modify view option" - if that's what you mean then i believe you still will have that option throu the browser.